# Quill Editor Component throws only in production -> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, quill, inertiajs

I'm using `quill editor` as `rich text editor component` and in development everything works fine but as soon as I launch my web app in a production environment, the component throws following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')
    at new t (cms-editor.58b2a676.js:1:4281)
    at T.value (main.5b8d6e17.js:809:22276)
    at T.value (main.5b8d6e17.js:810:2735)
    at main.5b8d6e17.js:809:22151
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at T.value (main.5b8d6e17.js:809:22109)
    at new Y (main.5b8d6e17.js:788:5408)
    at o (main.5b8d6e17.js:829:1661)
    at main.5b8d6e17.js:829:1411
    at Kt (main.5b8d6e17.js:4:656)
Gv @ main.5b8d6e17.js:4
or @ main.5b8d6e17.js:4
Kt @ main.5b8d6e17.js:4
wt @ main.5b8d6e17.js:4
t.__weh.t.__weh @ main.5b8d6e17.js:4
Do @ main.5b8d6e17.js:4
te @ main.5b8d6e17.js:4
mount @ main.5b8d6e17.js:4
t.mount @ main.5b8d6e17.js:4
setup @ main.5b8d6e17.js:831
(anonymous) @ main.5b8d6e17.js:12
Promise.then (async)
zh @ main.5b8d6e17.js:12
(anonymous) @ main.5b8d6e17.js:831
```

The top log message suggests that **`cms-editor`** seems to be the origin of the error:

```
<template>
  <div id="cms-editor" class="cms-editor">
    <quill-editor ref="quill" :modules="modules" :toolbar="toolbar" v-model:content="content" contentType="html"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter'
import {ref, watchEffect} from 'vue'
import {Quill} from "@vueup/vue-quill";

const props = defineProps({
    body: String,
    triggerEmit: Boolean
})

const content = ref(props.body || '')

const emit = defineEmits(['emitBody'])

watchEffect(async () => {
    if (props.triggerEmit) {
        const body = await compressHtml(content.value)
        emit('emitBody', body)
    }
})

const quill = ref(null)

Quill.debug('error')

const compressImage = (dataUrl, width, mime, resize) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl
        img.onload = () => {
            const height = Math.round(img.height / img.width * width)
            const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
            resolve(canvas.toDataURL(mime, resize));
        }
    })
}

const compressHtml = async (content) => {
    let body = content.split('<')
    let count = 1
    for (const id in body) {
        count = count + 1
        let el = body[id]
        if (el.substr(0, 3) == 'img') {
            const dataUrl = el.split('"')[1]
            const src = el.split('"')[1].split(',')[1]
            const mime = el.split('data:')[1].split(';')[0]
            const size = atob(src).length;
            if (size >= 250000) {
                let img_el = await compressImage(dataUrl, 600, mime, .9)
                    .then(res => {
                        return 'img src="' + res + '">';
                    })
                body[id] = img_el
            }
        }
    }
    return body.join('<')
}

const toolbar = [
    [{header: [1, 2, 3, false]}],
    [{size: ['small', false, 'large', 'huge']}],
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
    [{align: []}],
    [{list: 'ordered'}, {list: 'bullet'}],
    [{color: []}, {background: []}],
    ['link', 'image'],
    ['clean'],
]

const modules = {
    module: BlotFormatter,
}

var BaseImageFormat = Quill.import('formats/image');
const ImageFormatAttributesList = [
    'alt',
    'height',
    'width',
    'style'
];

//make quill image alignment work
class ImageFormat extends BaseImageFormat {
    static formats(domNode) {
        return ImageFormatAttributesList.reduce(function (formats, attribute) {
            if (domNode.hasAttribute(attribute)) {
                formats[attribute] = domNode.getAttribute(attribute);
            }
            return formats;
        }, {});
    }

    format(name, value) {
        if (ImageFormatAttributesList.indexOf(name) > -1) {
            if (value) {
                this.domNode.setAttribute(name, value);
            } else {
                this.domNode.removeAttribute(name);
            }
        } else {
            super.format(name, value);
        }
    }
}

Quill.register(ImageFormat, true);

</script>
```

The error is thrown instantly, when the component is loaded. The `props` do not seem to play a role because I tried commenting them out and the error still gets thrown. Any idea how I could debug this?

I'm using `inertia.js` if that is relevant.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Andrew No, after a few days of effortless headache, I've switched to TipTap. Getting into took some time but the syntax and level of control are way better, if you like to build from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Your blot formatter might be configured in a wrong way. I didn't really use this feature in my App, so I disabled / removed it and the production error disappears.

See issue here:
https://github.com/vueup/vue-quill/issues/315

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).